# Using Change data capture to populate data from Oracle to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle10g, etl, cdc

I have a production db running on Oracle 10g. I want to set up a data warehouse using a MySQL 5.5 database and ideally would like to use CDC to identify any changes to the live DB and populate those changes to the warehouse.

Has anyone done this?

Is it possible without the use of a third party ETL tool, if not can anyone recommend any software for the job?

Comment: I forgot to mention i am looking as using asyncronous CDC via the DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH package ideally.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use oracle database gateway for odbc.
It al depends how many tables you want to replicate and amount of data changed daily
You may end up writing a lot of triggers but it might slow down your database.
If you have creation and last modification fields you may use them as well.
Plus you can copy modified data only on schedule during of peak hours.